# Computed fields Odoo9

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I'm creating a module for student management in "Odoo9", in a part of that module I want to compute the average mark that a student get in a subject like "maths".I'm tryingto achieve that using this code, but I have a problem computing the "Avg-Maths" immediately after filling "Maths-1" and "Maths-2", it can only be computed after saving the student profile.Can someone help me please realizing the issue here? and how can I fix this?
[image]

```
#student class
class student_student(models.Model):
    '
    '
    '
    result_ids = fields.One2many("schoolresults.detail", "student_id", "School Results")
    '
    '
    '


class schoolresults_detail(models.Model):
    _name = "schoolresults.detail"
    _description = "Student's results."
    student_id = fields.Many2one("student.student", "Student", ondelete="cascade")
    subject_id = fields.Many2one("schoolresults.subject", "Subject")


    result_manual = fields.Float("Result")
    result = fields.Float(compute='_compute_value',store=True)
    manual = fields.Boolean(compute='_is_manual', default=False)

    @api.one
    @api.depends('manual')
    def _is_manual(self):
        self.manual = self.subject_id.my_id
    @api.one
    @api.depends('result_manual','subject_id','subject_id.my_id')
    def _compute_value(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        results = self.env['schoolresults.detail'].search([])
        total = 0
        for data in results:
            total += data.result_manual
        for data in results:
            #if the subject is the average of others 
            if data.subject_id.my_id:
                data.result = total


class schoolresults_subject(models.Model):
    _name = "schoolresults.subject"
    _description = "Student's subjects."
    my_id = fields.Integer(default=0)
    name = fields.Char("Subject")
```

Comment: Either the field should accept input or it should be calculated, but in your case avg is calculative and maths and physics marks are input. Don't mix-up the things. You need to add average of those subjects into the parent model.

Comment: That means that I cannot show the average field in the result_ids view, it will be shown in the student view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `student_id.result_ids.result_manual` to your depends list on `_compute_value`. That should trigger a recomputation.

Comment: The function is triggered but the avg-maths is not changing immediately after changing other field, It is only changing after saving the clicking save.another thing is that the function retrieve values from database not from the tree view.I think that i should that because self point to the the current row not all the recordsets. I have an idea of triggering the compute function from the student_student class, but then the problem is I cannot change the values of schoolresults_detail fields from student_student

Comment: OK, that could mean it would be an onchange (depends is ofcourse an onchange but with database persistence) on an x2many field. And that isn't possible without an "big" change in Odoo. For more information look [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2693)

Comment: Thank you for this one, I will play with those changes in odoo framewrok and I see if it could work

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my life and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

i think  after calculating the value you should assign it to your result field

```
@api.one
def _compute_method(self):
# compute average for this record 
self.result = calclated_value
```

but i don't see that you assign the value to the result field ?!! sot try to assign it that should do it

Comment: I did that, the problem is it update the result field of the current row when I update result_manual of the current row.I don't want this behavior.Instead it should update the other row "where subject is avgMath"  and it should be immediate.